# Silverlight WindowState.Maximized strange behavior

Tags: c#, silverlight, maximize-window

I have an out of browser Silverlight application that I have recently changed to be borderless  in order to make my own window. I have a Restore / Maximize button but its causing some strange behavior. The application starts and automatically maximizes. I can restore and maximize on the main monitor with no problem. If I restore, move to another monitor, then maximize, it just disappears. It seems like it maximizes off screen or something. Im just switching the WindowState using the code below. Any ideas?

```
App.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
App.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Edit:
I found some more info on what its doing. It seems like its putting the window way of to the side for some reason.

Here are the coordinates when I manually move it to where its supposed to be when maximized on the left monitor.

```
Left: -1920, Top: 0, Height: 1040, Width: 1920
```

If I move it and hit maximize it puts it at these coordinates

```
Left: -5760, Top: 0, Height: 1040, Width: 1920
```

Not sure what its up to. I suppose I could use pInvoke to get the resolution of each monitor and do the positioning myself, but it seems like I should need to.

Edit 2:
I tried using pInvoke to maximize the window and it does the same thing.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpCaption);

public static IntPtr FindHwnd(Window window)
{
    var oldTitle = window.Title;
    var id = oldTitle + "(" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ")";
    window.Title = id;
    var hwnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, id);
    window.Title = oldTitle;
    return hwnd;
}

ShowWindow(FindHwnd(Application.Current.MainWindow), SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Edit 3:
I put the window border back and also left my custom border and it works fine then. It seems like when the control doesn't have a border it causes the issue.

Comment: What version of Silverlight? 5?

Comment: Yes Silverlight 5. Also I am using MainWindow.DragMove() to move the window.